# scanindexforward() not working as expected while doing pagination in dynamodb

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries, amazon-dynamodb-index

I am using `DynamoDBEnchancedAsyncClient` to query `DynamoDB` using `GSI` and `pagination`. Below is the code that I am using to achieve the same. I am tying to `limit` the number of `items per page` and `number of pages sent to the subscriber of the Mono` using below code. I need to sort the records in each page in `descending` order using the `timestamp` and this is the `sort key` in my `GSI`. For this I am using `scanIndexForward(false)` below. However I `am not getting any records` in the page even though there are in total `4 records` that are present in `DynamoDB`.

```
SdkPublisher<Page<Customer>> query = secindex.query(QueryEnhancedRequest.builder().queryConditional(queryconditional).scanIndexForward(false)
        .limit(2).build())
     
Mono.from(PagePublisher.create(query().limit(1)))
```

`secindex` is the `DynamoDBAsyncIndex` which is the `GSI` . As per the above code, `1 page` should be returned to client with `2 records` however `none` are getting returned. Also If I remove `scanIndexForward(false)` then the result is as expected but sorted in `ascending` order. How do I make it return limited records in `descending` order ? Does the pagination work differently when the `scanIndexForward()` is supplied?

Comment: Can you add the `queryconditional` value and the value of a database item you expect to find?

Answer (score 0):

Without 100% knowing what your filters are on your dynamo call, i can only guess - but I've seen this sort of thing many times

so.

**Correction** limit is applied *before* the query is returned not after. This was incorrect below - but because of the nature of additional filters being applied after the return this could indeed result in 2 items being returned that are then filtered out and an ultimate return of 0
**end correction**

Dynamodb Query does not perform any filter/limits on the data before returning it. The only thing a standard query to dynamo can do is check Hash Key/Range Key with some basic Range Key filtering ( gt, lt, between, begins with ect) - all other filters on attributes that are not Hash/Range are done by the SDK you're using after getting back a set of responses.

1 - Query the dynamo with a Hash Key/Range Key combination and any filtering on Range.

2 - All items that match this are sent back - up to 1mb data. Anything more than that needs additional calls

<s>3 - Apply the limit to these results!</s> *this was incorrect, this is applied before being returned*

4 - Apply the filter to whats been limited!

5 - Then whatever is left is returned.

This means that what happens often when you are using filter conditions on a dynamo query, you may not actually get back what you expect to - because either they are on the next page and what is on the current page, nothing matches the filter so you get back 0.

Since you are also using Limit, when it sorts the data in the same order as the Sort Key (as scan index forward is false) then if the first two values don't match your other filters, you get 0 items back.

I would recommend you try querying all the items without any filters beyond just Hash/Range key - no other attribute filters.

Then filter the response manually on your side.

You also should be aware of the internal pagination of the SDKs for dynamo - it will only return 1mb amount of data from the Dyanmo in a single call.  Anything beyond that requires a second call including the LastEvaluatedKey that is returned in the first page of results. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Query.Pagination.html has more information.

If your system cannot afford to do the filtering itself after the query is called, then you need to re-evaluate your HashKey/SortKey combinations. Dynamo is best aligned in an Access Pattern schema - that is to say, I have X data and I will need Y data, so I will cause X to be a Hash Key, and the Y values to be different Range Keys under that X.

like as an example: User data. You might have a HashKey of "user_id".

Then you have several different patterns for Range_keys

meta# (with attributes of email, username, hashed and salted passwords, ect)
post#1
post#2
post#3
avatar#

and so you make a query on just Hash Key of the user id, you get all the info. Or if you have page with just their posts, you can do a query of hash key of user id and range key (begins with post#)

This is the most important aspect of a good dynamo schema - the ability to do queries on any thing you need with just a Hash Key or a HashKey and RangeKey

With a well understood set of access patterns that you will need, and a dynamo that is set up appropriately, then you should need no filters or limits, because your combination of Hash/Range key queries will be enough.

(this does sometimes mean a duplication of data! You may have the same information in a Post# item as you do in the Meta# item - ie they both contain usernames. This is OK as when you query for a post you need the user name - as well as when you query for the password/username to see if they match. - Dynamo as a NoSQL handles this very well, and very fast - a given Hash/Range key combination is basically considered its own table in terms of access, making queries VERY fast against it.)